# Behavior of RunOnce and GPO logon in windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, registry, system-administration

I register a command to start a process in RunOnce registry of HKCU so the process get a chance to kickstart in next log in based on few conditions. The command use a mapped drive path ( from Group policy logon script ). In Windows Server 2008, 2008 r2, and lower flavors, the process get started properly in the next log in session as the mapped drives are available from GPO's logon script. In Windows 7, I see RunOnce from HKCU gets processed before GPO logon script execute. Is there a way to change the processing order? Why does this specifically happen in windows 7?

Also what's the best practice ( RunOnce or startup folder? ) for a non-admin user to register a command at the time of next login session?

-Karthik

Answer (score 0):

In your group policy, make sure that "Run logon scripts synchronously" is enabled.  This can be found in Computer Configuration - Policies - Administrative Templates - System - Scripts.

Comment: harry, thanks for your reply. In server 2008, I see the option is listed as 'not configured'. This still allow logon script to execute first followed by RunOnce as expected. In windows 7, the behavior is different. could there be any registry setting that can alter the behavior?

Comment: Without this group policy setting, the OS is free to do whatever it likes.  All sorts of things might influence this, including the OS version, network performance, and random chance; best practice is to explicitly tell the system (via this setting) to do the logon scripts before anything else, then it will always work as expected.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the Drive Maps option in group policy preferences (new in Windows 7/2008R2) to create drive mappings instead of a logon script.  I believe these will always happen before RunOnce and Startup folder items are launched.